# How to find a syzygy module is graded free module over R?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-homomorphism, free-modules, graded-modules

I am a bit new to commutative algebra. It is an algorithmic question rather than mathematical.

Suppose that I have a graded polynomial ring $R = \oplus_{i \geq 0} R_i$ and a graded module $M=\oplus_{i \geq 0} M_i$ over $R$. According to *Hilbert's syzygy theorem*, I should stop resolving $M$ when the syzygy $\Omega_kM$ is **graded free** for $k \geq 1$:
$$
0 \rightarrow \Omega_1M \rightarrow F_0 \rightarrow M  \\ 0 \rightarrow \Omega_2M \rightarrow F_1 \rightarrow \Omega_1M \\ \vdots \\ 0 \rightarrow \Omega_kM \rightarrow F_{k-1} \rightarrow \Omega_{k-1}M,
$$
where $F_i$ is an appropriate free module, $\Omega_kM = \oplus_{i \geq 0} R(-d_i)$ (i.e. graded free over $R$), $d_i = \deg(\eta_i)$, and $\{\eta_i\}_i$ are basis.

My question is "How can we find that $\Omega_kM$ is **graded free**" in an algorithmic sense to stop calculating syzygies?

Edit:
Link to the solution: [syzygy_freeRes.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XjHrFiP5NeaB3n4UeUuH163NOLYi-1e1/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I don't know much about the theory, but Grobner Basis can be used. Please refer to the book of Cox, Little and O'shea.

Comment: Hello Youngsu! Thanks for the reply. I know how to compute the kernel basis from Sturmfels' book; but my problem is how to generate the chain of exact sequence for resolving syzygies via a proper algorithm and its relation to inclusion/exclusion principle. Such as Step#1: Do this. Step#2: Do that, etc. I heard Macaulay-2 has a method called **res(I)** to do that which also calculates transformations in polynomial entries. However, I could not find a paper or a documentation describing how it accomplishes that task.

Comment: Hi, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.01654.pdf is one of the papers that popped up when googling "groebner basis to find syzygy modules." You may want to check out other items, too. But I am pretty sure the book I mentioned has such an algorithm.

Comment: Thank you so much Youngsu. I think you are referring to Chapter-5. I will go through the entire chapter today and let you know. By the way, thanks for the paper too!

Comment: Hello Youngsu, I've just added a link to the algorithm in the question. If you know what free resolution, and short exact sequence (SES) are, please jump to page #4. I hope I could explain it plainly. Perhaps there is a better, compact way to show it; but my bg is not math. Thanks for your comments so far!

Comment: I appreciate the link, and I will check it out soon. Merry Christmas!